# Selecting all tables that uses a specific foriegn key value in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys

In MySQL I have a table Currency (id, name) and multiple tables that refers to its (id) and I want to know if there is any table that uses a specific Currency.id value.

Currency

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | USD |
| 2 | JD |

SomeTable

| id | currencyId |
| --- | --- |
| 112 | 1 |
| 345 | 2 |

How can I get all table names if the currencyId referenced to specific value of Currency table (for example: Currency.id = 1, SomeTable.currencyId = 1)?

Comment: You need at least two queries: one to get the table names referencing the currency table, then the query or queries you build based on this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the system table KEY_COLUMN_USAGE to find all references to the currency ID. Then use `CONCAT` and `GROUP_CONCAT` to build a query returning the table names containing a particular ID.

```
select 
  group_concat(
    concat('select ''', table_schema, '.', table_name, ''' where exists (select null from ', table_name, ' where ', column_name, ' = @id)')
    separator '\nunion all\n'
  ) as query
from information_schema.key_column_usage
where upper(referenced_table_schema) = 'FIDDLE' -- your schema name here
  and upper(referenced_table_name) = 'CURRENCY';
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/Jxi6K1TV

Comment: it gives me a half statement at the end because the tables using currencyId are many.

Comment: Too bad. Then remove the `GROUP_CONCAT`, i.e. only use the `CONCAT`. Thus you get one row per referencing table. You can include the `UNION ALL` at the end of the `CONCAT` list. Then copy/paste the results into an editor, remove the last `UNION ALL`, and you have your query.